# JavaFX HBox hide item

Tags: java, javafx-2

How can i hide an item in HBox, and made space used by this item available to other items.

```
TitledPane legendPane = new TitledPane("Legend", _legend);
legendPane.setVisible(false);
LineChart chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(_xAxis, _yAxis);

HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
hbox.getChildren().addAll(legendPane, chart);
```

In the above code i want the chart node to use all available space when the legend pane is hidden.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Before calling legendPane.setVisible, call:

```
legendPane.managedProperty().bind(legendPane.visibleProperty());
```

The [Node.managed](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#managedProperty) property prevents a node in a Scene from affecting the layout of other scene nodes.

Comment: That seems more direct that adding/removing the node.

Answer (score 7):

You can temporarily remove it from the scene:

```
legendPane.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            hbox.getChildren().add(legendPane);
        } else {
            hbox.getChildren().remove(legendPane);
        }
    }
});
```

Or manipulate its size:

```
legendPane.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            legendPane.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
            legendPane.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        } else {
            legendPane.setMaxSize(0, 0);
            legendPane.setMinSize(0, 0);

        }
    }
});
```