# Fixing number of columns in javafx TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have 4 columns in my dynamically generated tableView in javafx. But in th UI I get an additional column with no text set. I want to ramove it and keep just four columns. How can I do that?
Also the table is not responsive. I have set it to grow it on all the sides but only that extra column grows. All the other columns attain the width as given to them initially in the Scene Builder. I want the table to be responsive. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

That's not an empty column, just unused space.  You can use

`tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);`

to make the columns take up all available width.

I find a better solution is a percent width with bindings like https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152992/2855515

Comment: This works fine. I want to do one more thing, I have a listView adjacent to tableView. I want that listView does not appear in the UI. It should appear only when a button is clicked and should disappear when button is clicked again. When this listView is hidden I want the tableView to take complete space.

Comment: You should ask another question but it will be just something simple like putting them in a hbox and shrinking or removing the list.  Read this solution first.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200195/javafx-hbox-hide-item

Answer (score 0):

The CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY will remove the extra column but you're then forced to have all columns be the same width. You can use the percent width bindings as brian suggested but then when you try to manually adjust the columns it has really strange behavior. The fact that CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY does not respect the column widths is a known bug, the JIRA is here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8157687

After hacking around in the javafx source, I found the following solution to work the best for my project. It's not perfect but it's the best workaround I've been able to find. The logic is in that first block, the rest is mostly copypasta of the TableUtil class to make it self-contained with the necessary access control. Just instantiate this class instead of TableView and it should work.

```java
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomTableView<S> extends TableView {

   static boolean isFirstRun = true;
   static int widthOfVerticalScrollbarOnTheRight = 16;

   public CustomTableView() {
      super(FXCollections.<S>observableArrayList());

      Callback<ResizeFeatures, Boolean> resizeFeaturesBooleanCallback = new Callback<ResizeFeatures, Boolean>() {
         @Override
         public Boolean call(ResizeFeatures prop) {

            TableView<?> table = prop.getTable();
            List<? extends TableColumnBase<?, ?>> visibleLeafColumns = table.getVisibleLeafColumns();
            Boolean result = TableUtil.constrainedResize(prop, isFirstRun, CustomTableView.this.getWidth(), visibleLeafColumns);
            isFirstRun = false;
            return result;
         }
      };

      setColumnResizePolicy(resizeFeaturesBooleanCallback);
   }


   /**
    * A package protected util class used by TableView and TreeTableView to reduce
    * the level of code duplication.
    */
   public static class TableUtil {

      private TableUtil() {
         // no-op
      }

      static void removeTableColumnListener(List<? extends TableColumnBase> list,
                                            final InvalidationListener columnVisibleObserver,
                                            final InvalidationListener columnSortableObserver,
                                            final InvalidationListener columnSortTypeObserver,
                                            final InvalidationListener columnComparatorObserver) {

         if (list == null) return;
         for (TableColumnBase col : list) {
            col.visibleProperty().removeListener(columnVisibleObserver);
            col.sortableProperty().removeListener(columnSortableObserver);
            col.comparatorProperty().removeListener(columnComparatorObserver);

//            col.sortTypeProperty().removeListener(columnSortTypeObserver);
            if (col instanceof TableColumn) {
               ((TableColumn) col).sortTypeProperty().removeListener(columnSortTypeObserver);
            } else if (col instanceof TreeTableColumn) {
               ((TreeTableColumn) col).sortTypeProperty().removeListener(columnSortTypeObserver);
            }

            removeTableColumnListener(col.getColumns(),
                  columnVisibleObserver,
                  columnSortableObserver,
                  columnSortTypeObserver,
                  columnComparatorObserver);
         }
      }

      static void addTableColumnListener(List<? extends TableColumnBase> list,
                                         final InvalidationListener columnVisibleObserver,
                                         final InvalidationListener columnSortableObserver,
                                         final InvalidationListener columnSortTypeObserver,
                                         final InvalidationListener columnComparatorObserver) {

         if (list == null) return;
         for (TableColumnBase col : list) {
            col.visibleProperty().addListener(columnVisibleObserver);
            col.sortableProperty().addListener(columnSortableObserver);
            col.comparatorProperty().addListener(columnComparatorObserver);

            if (col instanceof TableColumn) {
               ((TableColumn) col).sortTypeProperty().addListener(columnSortTypeObserver);
            } else if (col instanceof TreeTableColumn) {
               ((TreeTableColumn) col).sortTypeProperty().addListener(columnSortTypeObserver);
            }

            addTableColumnListener(col.getColumns(),
                  columnVisibleObserver,
                  columnSortableObserver,
                  columnSortTypeObserver,
                  columnComparatorObserver);
         }
      }

      static void removeColumnsListener(List<? extends TableColumnBase> list, ListChangeListener cl) {
         if (list == null) return;

         for (TableColumnBase col : list) {
            col.getColumns().removeListener(cl);
            removeColumnsListener(col.getColumns(), cl);
         }
      }

      static void addColumnsListener(List<? extends TableColumnBase> list, ListChangeListener cl) {
         if (list == null) return;

         for (TableColumnBase col : list) {
            col.getColumns().addListener(cl);
            addColumnsListener(col.getColumns(), cl);
         }
      }

      static void handleSortFailure(ObservableList<? extends TableColumnBase> sortOrder,
                                    SortEventType sortEventType, final Object... supportInfo) {
         // if the sort event is consumed we need to back out the previous
         // action so that the UI is not in an incorrect state
         if (sortEventType == SortEventType.COLUMN_SORT_TYPE_CHANGE) {
            // go back to the previous sort type
            final TableColumnBase changedColumn = (TableColumnBase) supportInfo[0];
            revertSortType(changedColumn);
         } else if (sortEventType == SortEventType.SORT_ORDER_CHANGE) {
            // Revert the sortOrder list to what it was previously
            ListChangeListener.Change change = (ListChangeListener.Change) supportInfo[0];

            final List toRemove = new ArrayList();
            final List toAdd = new ArrayList();
            while (change.next()) {
               if (change.wasAdded()) {
                  toRemove.addAll(change.getAddedSubList());
               }

               if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                  toAdd.addAll(change.getRemoved());
               }
            }

            sortOrder.removeAll(toRemove);
            sortOrder.addAll(toAdd);
         } else if (sortEventType == SortEventType.COLUMN_SORTABLE_CHANGE) {
            // no-op - it is ok for the sortable type to remain as-is
         } else if (sortEventType == SortEventType.COLUMN_COMPARATOR_CHANGE) {
            // no-op - it is ok for the comparator to remain as-is
         }
      }

      private static void revertSortType(TableColumnBase changedColumn) {
         if (changedColumn instanceof TableColumn) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = (TableColumn) changedColumn;
            final TableColumn.SortType sortType = tableColumn.getSortType();
            if (sortType == TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(null);
            } else if (sortType == TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
            } else if (sortType == null) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
            }
         } else if (changedColumn instanceof TreeTableColumn) {
            TreeTableColumn tableColumn = (TreeTableColumn) changedColumn;
            final TreeTableColumn.SortType sortType = tableColumn.getSortType();
            if (sortType == TreeTableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(null);
            } else if (sortType == TreeTableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(TreeTableColumn.SortType.ASCENDING);
            } else if (sortType == null) {
               tableColumn.setSortType(TreeTableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
            }
         }
      }

      static enum SortEventType {
         SORT_ORDER_CHANGE,
         COLUMN_SORT_TYPE_CHANGE,
         COLUMN_SORTABLE_CHANGE,
         COLUMN_COMPARATOR_CHANGE
      }


      /**
       * The constrained resize algorithm used by TableView and TreeTableView.
       *
       * @param prop
       * @param isFirstRun
       * @param tableWidth
       * @param visibleLeafColumns
       * @return
       */
      public static boolean constrainedResize(ResizeFeaturesBase prop,
                                              boolean isFirstRun,
                                              double tableWidth,
                                              List<? extends TableColumnBase<?, ?>> visibleLeafColumns) {
         TableColumnBase<?, ?> column = prop.getColumn();
         double delta = prop.getDelta();

        /*
         * There are two phases to the constrained resize policy:
         *   1) Ensuring internal consistency (i.e. table width == sum of all visible
         *      columns width). This is often called when the table is resized.
         *   2) Resizing the given column by __up to__ the given delta.
         *
         * It is possible that phase 1 occur and there be no need for phase 2 to
         * occur.
         */

         boolean isShrinking;
         double target;
         double totalLowerBound = 0;
         double totalUpperBound = 0;

         if (tableWidth == 0) return false;

        /*
         * PHASE 1: Check to ensure we have internal consistency. Based on the
         *          Swing JTable implementation.
         */
         // determine the width of all visible columns, and their preferred width
         double colWidth = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < visibleLeafColumns.size(); i++) {
            if (i < visibleLeafColumns.size() - 1) {
               colWidth += visibleLeafColumns.get(i).getWidth();
            } else {
               colWidth += visibleLeafColumns.get(i).getWidth()+ widthOfVerticalScrollbarOnTheRight;
            }
         }

         if (Math.abs(colWidth - tableWidth) > 1) {
            isShrinking = colWidth > tableWidth;
            target = tableWidth;

            if (isFirstRun) {
               // if we are here we have an inconsistency - these two values should be
               // equal when this resizing policy is being used.
               for (TableColumnBase<?, ?> col : visibleLeafColumns) {
                  totalLowerBound += col.getMinWidth();
                  totalUpperBound += col.getMaxWidth();
               }

               // We run into trouble if the numbers are set to infinity later on
               totalUpperBound = totalUpperBound == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY ?
                     Double.MAX_VALUE :
                     (totalUpperBound == Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ? Double.MIN_VALUE : totalUpperBound);

               for (TableColumnBase col : visibleLeafColumns) {
                  double lowerBound = col.getMinWidth();
                  double upperBound = col.getMaxWidth();

                  // Check for zero. This happens when the distribution of the delta
                  // finishes early due to a series of "fixed" entries at the end.
                  // In this case, lowerBound == upperBound, for all subsequent terms.
                  double newSize;
                  if (Math.abs(totalLowerBound - totalUpperBound) < .0000001) {
                     newSize = lowerBound;
                  } else {
                     double f = (target - totalLowerBound) / (totalUpperBound - totalLowerBound);
                     newSize = Math.round(lowerBound + f * (upperBound - lowerBound));
                  }

                  double remainder = resize(col, newSize - col.getWidth());

                  target -= newSize + remainder;
                  totalLowerBound -= lowerBound;
                  totalUpperBound -= upperBound;
               }

               CustomTableView.isFirstRun = false;
            } else {
               double actualDelta = tableWidth - colWidth;
               List<? extends TableColumnBase<?, ?>> cols = visibleLeafColumns;
               resizeColumns(cols, actualDelta);
            }
         }

         // At this point we can be happy in the knowledge that we have internal
         // consistency, i.e. table width == sum of the width of all visible
         // leaf columns.

        /*
         * Column may be null if we just changed the resize policy, and we
         * just wanted to enforce internal consistency, as mentioned above.
         */
         if (column == null) {
            return false;
         }

        /*
         * PHASE 2: Handling actual column resizing (by the user). Based on my own
         *          implementation (based on the UX spec).
         */

         isShrinking = delta < 0;

         // need to find the last leaf column of the given column - it is this
         // column that we actually resize from. If this column is a leaf, then we
         // use it.
         TableColumnBase<?, ?> leafColumn = column;
         while (leafColumn.getColumns().size() > 0) {
            leafColumn = leafColumn.getColumns().get(leafColumn.getColumns().size() - 1);
         }

         int colPos = visibleLeafColumns.indexOf(leafColumn);
         int endColPos = visibleLeafColumns.size() - 1;

         // we now can split the observableArrayList into two subobservableArrayLists, representing all
         // columns that should grow, and all columns that should shrink
         //    var growingCols = if (isShrinking)
         //        then table.visibleLeafColumns[colPos+1..endColPos]
         //        else table.visibleLeafColumns[0..colPos];
         //    var shrinkingCols = if (isShrinking)
         //        then table.visibleLeafColumns[0..colPos]
         //        else table.visibleLeafColumns[colPos+1..endColPos];


         double remainingDelta = delta;
         while (endColPos > colPos && remainingDelta != 0) {
            TableColumnBase<?, ?> resizingCol = visibleLeafColumns.get(endColPos);
            endColPos--;

            // if the column width is fixed, break out and try the next column
            if (!resizingCol.isResizable()) continue;

            // for convenience we discern between the shrinking and growing columns
            TableColumnBase<?, ?> shrinkingCol = isShrinking ? leafColumn : resizingCol;
            TableColumnBase<?, ?> growingCol = !isShrinking ? leafColumn : resizingCol;

            //        (shrinkingCol.width == shrinkingCol.minWidth) or (growingCol.width == growingCol.maxWidth)

            if (growingCol.getWidth() > growingCol.getPrefWidth()) {
               // growingCol is willing to be generous in this case - it goes
               // off to find a potentially better candidate to grow
               List<? extends TableColumnBase> seq = visibleLeafColumns.subList(colPos + 1, endColPos + 1);
               for (int i = seq.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  TableColumnBase<?, ?> c = seq.get(i);
                  if (c.getWidth() < c.getPrefWidth()) {
                     growingCol = c;
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }
            //
            //        if (shrinkingCol.width < shrinkingCol.prefWidth) {
            //            for (c in reverse table.visibleLeafColumns[colPos+1..endColPos]) {
            //                if (c.width > c.prefWidth) {
            //                    shrinkingCol = c;
            //                    break;
            //                }
            //            }
            //        }


            double sdiff = Math.min(Math.abs(remainingDelta), shrinkingCol.getWidth() - shrinkingCol.getMinWidth());

//                System.out.println("\tshrinking " + shrinkingCol.getText() + " and growing " + growingCol.getText());
//                System.out.println("\t\tMath.min(Math.abs("+remainingDelta+"), "+shrinkingCol.getWidth()+" - "+shrinkingCol.getMinWidth()+") = " + sdiff);

            double delta1 = resize(shrinkingCol, -sdiff);
            double delta2 = resize(growingCol, sdiff);
            remainingDelta += isShrinking ? sdiff : -sdiff;
         }
         return remainingDelta == 0;
      }

      // function used to actually perform the resizing of the given column,
      // whilst ensuring it stays within the min and max bounds set on the column.
      // Returns the remaining delta if it could not all be applied.
      static double resize(TableColumnBase column, double delta) {
         if (delta == 0) return 0.0F;
         if (!column.isResizable()) return delta;

         final boolean isShrinking = delta < 0;
         final List<TableColumnBase<?, ?>> resizingChildren = getResizableChildren(column, isShrinking);

         if (resizingChildren.size() > 0) {
            return resizeColumns(resizingChildren, delta);
         } else {
            double newWidth = column.getWidth() + delta;

            if (newWidth > column.getMaxWidth()) {
               column.impl_setWidth(column.getMaxWidth());
               return newWidth - column.getMaxWidth();
            } else if (newWidth < column.getMinWidth()) {
               column.impl_setWidth(column.getMinWidth());
               return newWidth - column.getMinWidth();
            } else {
               column.impl_setWidth(newWidth);
               return 0.0F;
            }
         }
      }

      // Returns all children columns of the given column that are able to be
      // resized. This is based on whether they are visible, resizable, and have
      // not space before they hit the min / max values.
      private static List<TableColumnBase<?, ?>> getResizableChildren(TableColumnBase<?, ?> column, boolean isShrinking) {
         if (column == null || column.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
         }

         List<TableColumnBase<?, ?>> tablecolumns = new ArrayList<TableColumnBase<?, ?>>();
         for (TableColumnBase c : column.getColumns()) {
            if (!c.isVisible()) continue;
            if (!c.isResizable()) continue;

            if (isShrinking && c.getWidth() > c.getMinWidth()) {
               tablecolumns.add(c);
            } else if (!isShrinking && c.getWidth() < c.getMaxWidth()) {
               tablecolumns.add(c);
            }
         }
         return tablecolumns;
      }

      private static double resizeColumns(List<? extends TableColumnBase<?, ?>> columns, double delta) {
         // distribute space between all visible children who can be resized.
         // To do this we need to work out if we're shrinking or growing the
         // children, and then which children can be resized based on their
         // min/pref/max/fixed properties. The results of this are in the
         // resizingChildren observableArrayList above.
         final int columnCount = columns.size();

         // work out how much of the delta we should give to each child. It should
         // be an equal amount (at present), although perhaps we'll allow for
         // functions to calculate this at a later date.
         double colDelta = delta / columnCount;

         // we maintain a count of the amount of delta remaining to ensure that
         // the column resize operation accurately reflects the location of the
         // mouse pointer. Every time this value is not 0, the UI is a teeny bit
         // more inaccurate whilst the user continues to resize.
         double remainingDelta = delta;

         // We maintain a count of the current column that we're on in case we
         // need to redistribute the remainingDelta among remaining sibling.
         int col = 0;

         // This is a bit hacky - often times the leftOverDelta is zero, but
         // remainingDelta doesn't quite get down to 0. In these instances we
         // short-circuit and just return 0.0.
         boolean isClean = true;
         for (TableColumnBase<?, ?> childCol : columns) {
            col++;

            // resize each child column
            double leftOverDelta = resize(childCol, colDelta);

            // calculate the remaining delta if the was anything left over in
            // the last resize operation
            remainingDelta = remainingDelta - colDelta + leftOverDelta;

            //      println("\tResized {childCol.text} with {colDelta}, but {leftOverDelta} was left over. RemainingDelta is now {remainingDelta}");

            if (leftOverDelta != 0) {
               isClean = false;
               // and recalculate the distribution of the remaining delta for
               // the remaining siblings.
               colDelta = remainingDelta / (columnCount - col);
            }
         }

         // see isClean above for why this is done
         return isClean ? 0.0 : remainingDelta;
      }
   }
}
```