# JavaFX Flowplane Layout when setVisible(False) component

Tags: javafx

When setting a component to setVisible(false) the Flowplane keeps the space the button occupied, instead of moving all to the left.

Is there a way, to stop the flowplane retaining the space and moving all components up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX HBox hide item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200195/javafx-hbox-hide-item)